# Why is the generic parameter not casting?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm missing something basic, but I can't figure it out. Given:

```
abstract class EventBase {}
class SpecialEvent : EventBase {}
```

Over in another class I want to allow callers to be able to `RegisterFor<SpecialEvent>(x => {...})`

```
public class FooHandler {
{
    internal Dictionary<Type, Action<EventBase>> _validTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Action<EventBase>>();

    internal void RegisterFor<T>(Action<T> handlerFcn) where T: EventBase
    {
        _validTypes.Add(typeof(T), handlerFcn);
    }
 }
```

However, the `_validTypes.Add` line does not compile. It cannot convert a `Action<T>` to an `Action<EventBase>`. The constraint specifies that `T` must be derived from `EventBase`, so what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: `Action<SpecialEvent>` can process only `SpecialEvent`, but `Action<EventBase>` should be able to process any `EventBase`. Thus `Action<SpecialEvent>` is **not** `Action<EventBase>`, but `Action<EventBase>` is `Action<SpecialEvent>`.

Comment: `Action<SpecialEvent>` isn't assignable to `Action<EventBase>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# is correct to disallow that. To understand why, consider this situation:

```
// This is your delegate implementation
void SpecialAction(SpecialEvent e) {
    Console.WriteLine("I'm so special!");
}

// This is another EventBase class
class NotSoSpecialEvent : EventBase {}

void PureEvil(Action<EventBase> handlerFcn) where T: EventBase {
    handlerFcn(new NotSoSpecialEvent()); // Why not?
}
```

Let's imagine that C# allows you to pass `Action<SpecialEvent>` for `Action<EventBase>`. Here is what would happen next:

```
PureEvil(SpecialAction); // Not allowed
```

Now `PureEvil` will try passing `NotSoSpecialEvent` to delegate `SpecialAction` that takes `SpecialEvent`, which must never happen.

Answer (score 4):

Action delegates are contravariant - the type is defined as `Action<in T>`. That has an implication on how substitution principle works when applied to actions.

Consider two types: `B` (base) and `D` (derived). Then `Action<B>` is *more derived* than `Action<D>`. This implies the following behavior:

```
class B { }
class D : B { }
...
Action<D> derivedAction = ...
Action<B> baseAction = derivedAction;  // Fails
Action<D> derivedAction1 = baseAction; // Succeeds
```

In your example, with `SpecialEvent` being the type deriving from `EventBase`, you are only allowed to assign `Action<SpecialEvent> = Action<EventBase>`, but not the other way around (as you are attempting).

Since you are already checking the event type before storing the delegates in the dictionary, then you don't have to insist on storing strongly typed delegates - let alone that you cannot insist on strong typing due to contravariance of `Action` delegates.

You can store anything you like in the dictionary, e.g. `Delegate` or plain `object` and then downcast to a concrete `Action<T>` when the time comes to fetch the `Action` delegate from the collection.

```
public class FooHandler
{
    internal Dictionary<Type, object> _validTypes = 
        new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    internal void RegisterFor<T>(Action<T> handlerFcn) 
        where T: EventBase
    {
        _validTypes.Add(typeof(T), handlerFcn);
    }

    internal Action<T> Find<T>()
        where T : EventBase =>
        (Action<T>)_validTypes[typeof(T)];
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Action<SpecialEvent>` cannot be used as `Action<EventBase>`.

Use `Delegate` to abstract the parameters and then cast it back:

```
public class FooHandler
{
    internal Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _validTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    internal void RegisterFor<T>(Action<T> handlerFcn) where T : EventBase
    {
        _validTypes.Add(typeof(T), handlerFcn);
    }

    internal void ExecuteHandler<T>(T value) where T : EventBase
    {
        var handler = (Action<T>)_validTypes[typeof(T)];
        handler(value);
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var handler = new Action<SpecialEvent>(ev => { Console.WriteLine("works!"); });
FooHandler.RegisterFor<SpecialEvent>(handler);
FooHandler.ExecuteHandler(new SpecialEvent());
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got an `Action<SpecialEvent>`, which is only known to handle `SpecialEvent`. `Action<EventBase>` means *any* `EventBase` can be passed to it. That makes the conversion unsafe.

In your case, I'd opt for a `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>` instead, where each `T` key is paired with an `Action<T>` value. If you can ensure you only add values of the correct type, you can safely cast the delegate back to `Action<T>` when you want to invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

What if some `Action<EventBase>` in the `Dictionary` is an `Action<UnexpectedEvent>` instead of an `Action<SpecialEvent>`? `Action<T>` is contravariant, but it is not covariant.

see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one/

If you happen to *know* that the types should work out, and/or want an exception if the types conflict, you can wrap it in another action that performs a cast, like so:

```
_validTypes.Add(typeof(T), eventBase => handlerFcn((T)eventBase));
```